# Query for results ordered by column of association table, most recent association only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting, mysql

given the following schema

```
class User
  has_many :page_views
  #[id]
end

class Page
  has_many :page_views
  #[id]
end

class PageView
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :page
  #[id, created_at, updated_at]
end
```

How can i query for a given page, all users most recent page views in order by created_at date. One row per user, showing only their most recent view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the PageViews with the maximum created_at for each user_id for a particular page_id.  This is a representation of this query in SQL:

```
SELECT max(created_at) AS last_visit, page_views.* 
FROM page_views 
WHERE (page_id = 1) 
GROUP BY user_id 
ORDER BY last_visit DESC
```

In Rails 3, you can write this like so:

```
Page.first.page_views.group(:user_id).select('max(created_at) AS last_visit, page_views.*').order('last_visit DESC')
```

Comment: I'm having a problem with the select part. If i take out ", *" then the query works, when i add that back it breaks. How can i get * as well as last_visit?

Comment: Try "max(created_at) AS last_visit, page_views.*" for the select component.  I updated above.

Comment: it also works to put * first e.g. "SELECT *, max(created_at) AS last_visit FROM"

Comment: Why is the last_visit field being returned as a string instead of a datetime?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
class Page
  has_many :page_views
  has_many :recent_page_views, :class_name => "PageView",
    :joins => "INNER JOIN (
      SELECT     a.id, COUNT(*) AS ranknum
      FROM       page_views AS a
      INNER JOIN page_views AS b ON a.user_id = b.user_id AND 
                                    a.page_id = b.page_id AND 
                                    a.created_at <= b.created_at
      GROUP BY   a.id
      HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
    ) AS d ON (page_views.id = d.id)",
    :order => "page_views.created_at"

 has_many :recent_viewers, :through => :recent_page_views, 
            :source => :user, :order => "page_views.created_at"
end
```

Now

```
page.recent_viewers
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer as well! I have selected the other one for its simplicity, though i do appreciate your answer as well.

Comment: Well if you need to access any of the `User` model attributes, then this solution is better. In the other solution will make N trips to DB if you have to get the details of the user.